# how to get a json property by index

Tags: android, gson, android-volley

in a json file i have several properties, some of them contains one object and some of them are array of objects. the property that contains array of objects is called "products".
but i know the position of that property the i want to parse it is number 3. so to parse the contents of the property that is called "products"

**code**:

```
 private void fetchPosts2() {
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, API_BASE_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(response));
            String json = null;
            JSONObject jresponse = null;

            try {
                jresponse = response.getJSONObject(3); //the arguments 3 is marked with red it is expected to be a string???
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "" + jresponse);//always null


            /*String data = "{ ... }";
            Object json = new JSONTokener(data).nextValue();
            if (json instanceof JSONObject);

            else if (json instanceof JSONArray)*/
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `JsonArrayRequest` instead of `JsonObjectRequest` to get element with index.